# What are the rules for naming Kafka topics (0.9)?

Tags: apache-kafka

As in, what characters aren't allowed? I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Need this to implement proper error-checking. Thank you!

Comment: For kafka 1.10 / 1.11, please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062904/what-are-apache-kafka-topic-name-limitations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.9.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/common/Topic.scala#L25), it looks like ASCII alphanumerics, `.`, `_` and `-` are valid characters in a topic name.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful.

When you execute `--create` command with supposedly wrong topic name, the kafka commandline throws error with valid topic name requirements as:

Command:

```
[hduser@node1 ~]$  kafka-topics --zookeeper node1:2181 --create --topic time#test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Error:

```
Error while executing topic command : topic name time#test is illegal, 
contains a character other than ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'
[2016-07-13 23:31:02,513] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: 
topic name time#test is illegal, 
contains a character other than ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-'
(kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```